# Help need with binding of jquery .error()

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I need some assistance with some javascript/jquery I have put in place. The function of this client side script is to set an event handler of all images within a particular selector on a page and if the image doesnt load (eg. not found), then its removed. My client side script is as follows, triggered in the document.ready of the external javascript file.

```
$('.imagecontainer').error(function() { ($this).parent().hide(); });
```

This works, sometimes! Sometimes when the page loads it works correctly, more time it works correctly for some images but the majority of the time it doesnt work at all. What it does if the image doesnt load, the surrounding anchor tag ie. the images parent is hidden. I have included alerts in the function to check when its called and it is triggered sometime but not all the time.

So I am wondering where I am going wrong. The path/src of the image is set in server side code by C# as the path is derived on the server side and cant be changed.

Any tips or ideas on this? I read somewhere that this event should be bound prior to the source of the image is set but not sure if this is achievable as the source of the image is set in the server side.

Once I have this resolved (hopefully), I have another problem. Some of the image are dynamically loaded by a user action and are not present on the page at run time. I have got around this for 99% of events by using the jquery syntax .live('click', function) etc. Does anyone know if I can do similar with the .error or how I can set it up.

Comment: tldr.................................... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things to note:

Your snippet there has a syntax error.  You have `($this).parent().hide();` instead of `$(this).parent().hide();`.

Review the [.error()](http://api.jquery.com/error/) documentation.  Specifically, there were two things I noted.  First is the observation that the call may not work properly if you are running locally.  Second, in the comments, someone observed the following:

> It uses the onerror callback. This
>   callback is only defined for img tags.
>   Some browsers (IE,FF,...) support this
>   callback on other objects too. This is
>   great for a global error catching
>   system (window.onerror). This
>   behaviour is NOT conform to standards.
>   WebKit for example does not fire this
>   callback!

Based on the small snippet you provided, it looks like you might be targeting an element that contains an image, rather than the image itself.  This may very well be the source of your problem.

Comment: Ender, thanks for your assistance. I changed my syntax to $('.imagecontainer').find('img').error(function() { $(this).parent().hide(); }); I also tried it on a web server and no change - works sometimes. Interestingly if I include an alert in the callback function, it works fine. Its like that slows down the page load for the event to be set on all images. Anyone got any other ideas as how I can rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround to my problem. It is as follows:

My above method doesn't work if the dom load event fires before the img error event. So I had to change my code to wait for  the window.onload event to fire, then check if any of the images are broken.

```
  $(window).bind('load', function() {
        $('.imagecontainer').find('img').each(function() {
            if ((typeof this.naturalWidth != "undefined" && this.naturalWidth == 0) || this.readyState == 'uninitialized') {
                // Image not available
                $(this).parent().hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

This seems to do the trick nicely.

However I have one issue. If the image is dynamically loaded eg. In a modal popup or via jquery ajax call, it does not work. I have got around this in the past by using .live() for my jquery. Is there any way of incorporating the .live() function in to the above? Or an alternative to handle dynamically loaded images.